# Remapped keys won't work when combined

Tags: key-bindings, navigation

I have these lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
" Remap movement 
nnoremap j h                                                                                                      
nnoremap k j                                                                                                      
nnoremap l k                                                                                                      
nnoremap é l
```

This seems to work properly for simple navigation, but utterly fails when I want to have movements combined with actions, eg. `d2k` should delete 2 lines downwards, but it actually moves upwards (as if i did not remap the key `k`. How do I correctly do the remapping, so that every command obeys it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer, I needed to add separate lines like this:

```
" Remap movement keys for operations                                                                                  
onoremap j h                                                                                                          
onoremap k j                                                                                                          
onoremap l k                                                                                                          
onoremap é l
```

Comment: You *also* need to add visual mode if you want it to work while selecting lines. That can be done with `vnoremap` or `xnoremap`